# Kafka Streams - missing source topic

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm working at a Kafka Streams topology and sometimes, after changing the applicationId and/or clientId properties I'm receiving an error on a specific kafka stream: "`Missing source topic stream.webshop.products.prices.5 durign assignment. Returning error INCOMPLETE_SOURCE_TOPIC_METADATA`". I have set the `create.topic=true` property in the server.properties of every Kafka node, but it seems that the topic for this stream is not created.

Here is my Kafka Streams topology:

```
    package ro.orange.eshop.productindexer.domain

import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Printed
import ro.orange.digital.avro.Aggregate
import ro.orange.digital.avro.Key
import ro.orange.digital.avro.Price
import ro.orange.digital.avro.StockQuantity
import ro.orange.eshop.productindexer.infrastructure.configuration.kafka.makeStoreProvider
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture

class SaleProductTopology(
        private val streamNameRepository: IStreamNameRepository,
        private val saleProductMapper: ISaleProductMapper,
        private val productRatingMapper: IProductRatingMapper,
        private val productStockMapper: IProductStockMapper,
        private val lazyKafkaStreams: CompletableFuture<KafkaStreams>
) {
    fun streamsBuilder(): StreamsBuilder {
        val streamsBuilder = StreamsBuilder()
        val productsStream = streamsBuilder.stream<Key, Aggregate>(streamNameRepository.inputWebshopProductsTopic)
        val productPricesStream = streamsBuilder.stream<Key, Price>(streamNameRepository.productsPricesStreamTopic)
        val productsRatingsStream = streamsBuilder.stream<Key, Aggregate>(streamNameRepository.inputProductRatingsTopic)
        val inputProductsStockStream = streamsBuilder.stream<Key, Aggregate>(streamNameRepository.inputProductsStockTopic)

        val productsStockStream = inputProductsStockStream
                .mapValues(productStockMapper::aStockQuantity)
        productsStockStream.to(streamNameRepository.productsStockStreamTopic)

        streamsBuilder.globalTable<Key, StockQuantity>(
                streamNameRepository.productsStockStreamTopic,
                Materialized.`as`(streamNameRepository.productsStockGlobalStoreTopic)
        )

        val quantityProvider = lazyKafkaStreams.makeStoreProvider<StockQuantity>(streamNameRepository.productsStockGlobalStoreTopic)

        val saleProductsTable = productsStream
                .groupByKey()
                .reduce({ _, aggregate -> aggregate }, Materialized.`as`(streamNameRepository.saleProductsStoreTopic))
                .mapValues { aggregate -> saleProductMapper.aSaleProduct(aggregate, quantityProvider) }

        saleProductsTable.toStream().print(Printed.toSysOut())

        val productPricesTable = productPricesStream
                .groupByKey()
                .reduce({ _, price -> price }, Materialized.`as`(streamNameRepository.productsPricesStoreTopic))

        productPricesTable.toStream().print(Printed.toSysOut())

        val productsRatingsTable = productsRatingsStream
                .groupByKey()
                .reduce({ _, aggregate -> aggregate }, Materialized.`as`(streamNameRepository.productsRatingsStoreTopic))
                .mapValues { aggregate -> productRatingMapper.aProductRating(aggregate) }

        productsRatingsTable.toStream().print(Printed.toSysOut())

        val productsStockTable = productsStockStream
                .groupByKey()
                .reduce { _, aggregate -> aggregate }

        saleProductsTable
                .leftJoin(productPricesTable) { saleProduct, price -> saleProductMapper.aPricedSaleProduct(saleProduct, price) }
                .leftJoin(productsRatingsTable) { saleProduct, rating -> saleProductMapper.aRatedSaleProduct(saleProduct, rating) }
                .leftJoin(productsStockTable) { saleProduct, stockQuantity -> saleProductMapper.aQuantifiedSaleProduct(saleProduct, stockQuantity) }
                .mapValues { saleProduct -> AggregateMapper.aSaleProductAggregate(saleProduct) }
                .toStream()
                .to(streamNameRepository.saleProductsTopic)

        return streamsBuilder
    }
}
```

Comment: What's `stream.webshop.products.prices.5`? Is this `productsPricesStreamTopic`? It should be available before starting the Kafka Streams app. `KafkaStreams` won't create it since it's a source.

Comment: Yes, that stream is created by using productsPricesStreamTopic and it's a source. But why Kafka can't create that stream automatically like it does with every other topic.

Comment: @DinaBogdan I'm running into INCOMPLETE_SOURCE_TOPIC_METADATA error though I created the topic well before running the stream application.  Do you have any piece of advise for me?  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @jacek-laskowski wrote:

> KafkaStreams won't create it since it's a source

It is by design, because if one of the source topic where created automatically (it would have **default** number of partitions) and second in advance by user the number of partitions might be different. When KStream/KTable are joined they must have same number of partition - this is crucial assumption.

User has to create the topics consciously with proper number of partitions (for the number of stream processing threads that is one of the ways to control performance of Kafka Streams applications).

Read up [Managing Streams Application Topics](https://kafka.apache.org/23/documentation/streams/developer-guide/manage-topics.html#streams-developer-guide-topics-user).

Comment: I was wondering if I thought right about this design of the Kafka Streams. But it seems to have a lot of sense to not create automatically the stream topic.